# youtube video not working in Webview with anyDensity set to false

Tags: android

On jelly beans android device (also ICS I believe), youtube videos in in an frame inside an android WebView stopped working in our apps many weeks ago: no video (black screen) but can hear sounds and see video controls.
I finally found one clue about what's preventing them from working.
Seems like the following needs to be set in the manifest for the video to work:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="8"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
```

Also on a side note, the video works fine after we click on the full screen youtube button (but I do not want to use fullscreen).

1) and 2) are not an issue for us, we can set those in the manifest (but i wonder why hardware acceleration is required).
But 3) we can't (for different reasons).

Does anyone know why anyDensity sets to false breaks videos and if there is any workaround?

some info about the apk to reproduce the issue:
apk was built with android 3.0
key extract of the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
<!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="true" -->
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name=".TestHTML5WebView"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>

...
```

html code used for the youtube video:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            window.onerror = function(errorMsg) {
                    try {
                            alert(errorMsg);
                    }
                    catch(err) {
                            alert('An expected error occurred. please try again later!');
                    }
            }
</script>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body {
                    background: #000;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
            }

            .video1 {
                    width: 90%;
                    height: 90%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="video1">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hH9Kx06oO_0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

to reproduce the issue, you can use the source code from http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/checkout (just make sure you update the manifest.xml with the values indicated at the top of this post, targetSdkVersion, hardwareAccelerated, android:anyDensity).

thanks.

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

For embedded video, the app needs surfacetexture class. This requrires android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to be set to true.
  according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html, android:anyDensity="false" should not be set to false.
  fullscreen video uses surfaceview, surfaceview has no requirement on hardware acceleration.

Comment: thanks for the explanation for hardwareAccelerated. But unfortunately I need android:anyDensity="false" in this application and cannot change that in the short term. Any idea why the video won't work with anyDensity="false"?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube Recently released player for android :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/